# nginx reverse proxy with Docker - Connection refused while connecting to upstream

Tags: docker, nginx, proxy, docker-compose

## Environment setup

I have an application which is composed by some services:

- jenkins server
- nginx server with angular
- nginx server as a proxy

Those services are defined in the `docker-compose` file:

```
    version: '3'
services:
  reverse:
    container_name: reverse-proxy
    build:
      context: /app/mywallet/MyWalletFe/reverse-proxy
    ports:
      - "80:80"
    networks:
      - net
  jenkins:
    container_name: jenkins
    image: jenkins/jenkins
    volumes:
      - "$PWD/jenkins_home:/var/jenkins_home"
      - "/var/run/docker.sock:/var/run/docker.sock"
    networks:
      - net
  angular:
    container_name: mywallet_fe
    build:
      context: /app/mywallet/MyWalletFe
    networks:
      - net
networks:
  net:
```

I defined the following configuration file for the `reverse-proxy`:

```
upstream client {
  # angular is the name of the service in docker-compose file
  server angular:4200;
}


upstream jenkins {
  server jenkins:8080;
}

server {
  listen 80;

  location / {
    proxy_pass http://client;
  }

  location /jenkins {
    proxy_pass http://jenkins;
  }
}
```

Finally, here is the `Dockerfile` for the `reverse-proxy` service, which copies the configuration file in the nginx container:

```
FROM nginx
# override default files if present
COPY ./default.conf /etc/nginx/conf.d/default.conf
```

### Goal

My goal is to access Jenkins with `SERVER_IP/jenkins`

### Output

When I run the whole application and try to access to `SERVER_IP/jenkins`, I get the following error in the reverse-proxy logs:

> 2020/04/15 21:44:55 [error] 6#6: *10 connect() failed (111: Connection
>   refused) while connecting to upstream, client: MY_CLIENT_IP, server: ,
>   request: "GET /login?from=%2Fjenkins HTTP/1.1", upstream:
>   "http://172.18.0.5:4200/login?from=%2Fjenkins", host: "SERVER_IP",
>   referrer: "http://SERVER_IP/jenkins" MY_CLIENT_IP 
>   [15/Apr/2020:21:44:55 +0000] "GET /favicon.ico HTTP/1.1" 502 559
>   "http://SERVER_IP/login?from=%2Fjenkins" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT
>   10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/80.0.3987.163 Safari/537.36" "-" 2020/04/15 21:44:55 [error]
>   6#6: *10 connect() failed (111: Connection refused) while connecting
>   to upstream, client: MY_CLIENT_IP, server: , request: "GET
>   /favicon.ico HTTP/1.1", upstream:
>   "http://172.18.0.5:4200/favicon.ico", host: "SERVER_IP",
>   referrer: "http://SERVER_IP/login?from=%2Fjenkins"

where `MY_CLIENT_IP` is my laptop IP and `SERVER_IP` is the IP of the server where the application runs.

What's wrong in the configuration of the reverse proxy? If I expose the jenkins and angular services I can reach them, while through the proxy I can't.

#### Similar question, which doesn't help me (or I don't understand how would those help me)

- [Docker nginx reverse proxy returns 502 bad gateway "connection refused while connecting to upstream"](https://stackoverflow.com/q/42475329/2993413)
- [Connection refused while connection to upstream - Docker](https://stackoverflow.com/q/55052784/2993413)
- [connect() failed (111: Connection refused) while connecting to upstream for nginx+php-fpm docker](https://stackoverflow.com/q/51122146/2993413)
- [docker nginx connection refused while connecting to upstream](https://stackoverflow.com/q/36923214/2993413)